# Select html through input:checked - pure css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Just wanted to know if anyone knew a way I can select and style the html tag directly after looking for :checked in css.

```
#btnControl:checked ??? html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated! : )

Best, Jonathan

Comment: there is no parent selector in css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select parent using CSS. But you can use `class` to do this work. Use javascript to add/remove class to element. When `checkbox` checked, add class to `html` and when checkbox unchecked, remove class of html.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(){ 
    if (checkbox.checked)
        html.classList.add("checked")
    else
        html.classList.remove("checked")
});
```

```css
html.checked {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox">Click on checkbox</label>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Pretty bummed that we can't do this yet in css as I'm trying to stay away from javascript as much as possible.